WezTerm shortcut to close split pane

This is a tab with 2 panes, I want to close just the second pane.


Is there a shortcut to close the current (focused) split pane?

Could you share with us the research you've done and what you have tried regarding this? Did you search Wezterm's documentation at least? I used "split pane close" on the Wezterm documentation site and found what appears to be an answer: https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/config/lua/keyassignment/CloseCurrentPane.html?h=pane+close

@music2myear I think you're confusing panel with splited panel or perhaps my question wasn't clear.

"Pane" and "panel" may be different, but they may be the same. Your image may be cropped too tightly, and your text explanation still doesn't indicate the research you've done, or define whether you're referring to a "pane" or a "panel". Please use the EDIT button and clarify and expand on your question.

By default - no. Remember that WezTerm has barely any defaults and relies on user configurability.
To add keyboard bindings, you have to edit config.keys table in your configuration LUA. A list of all available actions that you can assign can be found here. The action for what you need is called CloseCurrentPane as others have mentioned. So this would be an example to bind it to Ctrl + W and close the pane instantly:
local wezterm = require 'wezterm'
local config = {}

config.keys = {
  {
    key = 'w',
    mods = 'CTRL',
    action = wezterm.action.CloseCurrentPane { confirm = false },
  },
}

return config


Windows/Linux/macOS:
Ctrl + Shift + W
This shortcut closes the currently active split-pane.
local wezterm = require 'wezterm'

return {
  keys = {
    -- Add a shortcut for closing the current pane
    {
      key = 'w',
      mods = 'CTRL|SHIFT',
      action = wezterm.action.CloseCurrentPane { confirm = true },
    },
  },
}


The answer is confusing as it kind of suggests there's a default keybinding. Please format your answers and be way more detailed next time.
